# multiple classes in the same css in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Good morning. I've two document CCS, one contain Material Design Lite CSS and other is been created by me for customize WP-login.
I'd ask if it's possible write some classes written in Material Design Lite CSS in one class created in my customize WP-login CSS?
Cause for customize WP-login I can't modify his HTML, so I can modify this file by creating another CSS and overwriting class of original WP-login CSS.

Comment: Please check my answer and replay your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to functions.php to have WordPress load your new stylesheet.

```
function custom_login_stylesheet() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-login', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/login/login-styles.css' );
}
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_login_stylesheet' );
```

Now any CSS you add to this stylesheet will be loaded for the login page. This enables you to change any part of the design to your liking.

You can refer this alos: https://torquemag.io/2016/08/customize-wordpress-login-page/

Hope this works for you.

Comment: I've already done this.. but the problem is that i want import class from an other css in this css.. Can I do that??

Comment: You can do like this : @import url("navigation.css"); /* Using a url */

Comment: Please check my answer and replay your feedback.

Comment: You should at least upvote, for developer encouragement.